# Can you use an opto-coupler to isolate the incoming supply from the output

Tags: power-supply

I would like to breakout the 5v and 12v outputs from my PC's psu. This is because of convience and accessibility. Would it be possible to use an optocoupler to isolate the supply coming from the psu? so that in the event of a dead short, it won't cause my pc to reset itself. Am only asking for a minimum 1A output for both rails. Ideally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Opto-couplers transmit *signal*, not power.

If you are worried about shorting the output of the same power supply the PC is using, then it's probably best if you don't use it for that.  You could put a regular fuse in series, but that will take a little time to react and won't protect against the immediate glitch.  A "polyfuse" has enough resistance that even a short on the outside probably won't glitch the supply inside the PC enough to matter, but you have to be aware of the series resistance.

The PC power supply is unlikely to let a short damage it, but if you might be doing bad things like shorting it, you really should get a separate bench supply for powering your questionable stuff.

Comment: I once had a board that was powered via ribbon cable connected to a PC game port fail shorted, drawing enough current to melt the cable, without disrupting the attached PC (it didn't even reboot--kept right on going as though nothing had happened)

Comment: wow that would be spectacular!! Much spectacular then the supply I blew up the other week. It was as if I was mixing so kind of magic potion.  Plenty of smoke even when I turned it off. I think I will use a seperate supply and deal with the cable mess and slight inaccessibility

Comment: @Ageis: Actually, it wasn't spectacular at all; I don't think I even noticed the cable was melted until after I brushed my finger against the board on the side opposite a chip which had gone into meltdown.  Had to suck on it for awhile to ease the pain.  Good thing I didn't touch the chip.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a DC-DC isolated switching power supply to do what you want to do and they arent cheap.

My question to you is what will you be using the external power supply hook up for? If its for powering projects or accessories I would just buy 5v & 12V switching supply, they are very cheap nowadays. That or use another PC ATX power supply by putting a light load on the 5V bus and grounding the power up pin.

Answer (score 1):

It's only 100mA, not the 1A you requested, but Analog Devices has [a line](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/digital-isolators/products/index.html#isoPower) of RF-based digital isolators that are also capable of providing power on the isolated side.  The [ADuM5000](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/digital-isolators/adum5000/products/product.html), for example, takes 5V in and provides a regulated 3.3V or 5V output at up to 500 mW.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an isolated DC-DC converter.  They aren't expensive.  A recent BOM of mine used a part from [The CUI VBT1-SMT Series.](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=ffec242a) [THIS PART](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VBT1-S5-S5-SMT/102-1397-1-ND/989923) is a 5V-5V converter that can provide 200mAmps with 1kV of isolation for under $6.  I'd read the data sheet very carefully to see how it will protect you from short, and if you're not satisfied, fuse it.

Comment: You say it's not expensive and Mr.Tea says it's not cheap. 6 dollar can be a lot, especially if the BOM cost must be kept under 7 dollar :). In any case, it's 200mA, not 1A.

Comment: Oops, missed the 1A requirement, but the way the question is worded, I'd be surprised if this was anything other than a one-off. The part number should still land the OP in the right search menu.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible but not practical to opto-couple electrical power, think big expensive, hot LED shining on a high-efficiency photovoltaic array.

for this reason most people use transformers for power isolation. if you need 5V or 12V isolated buy an isolated supply from your favourite supplier

Comment: A typical "opto-coupler" contains no photovoltaic cells.  Usually the outputs are phototransistors that are turned on by the light, but don't provide any direct power out.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I think Jasen knows that: "It's possible but not practical".  If one needed a milliwatt or so of power with a million volts isolation, didn't mind wasting a few watts at the supply end, and couldn't afford any mechanical vibration, delivering power optically might be better than any other alternative (I don't think a transformer with a million volts of isolation would be very efficient; using brushless motor and generator might be more efficient than using LEDs and photovoltaics, but it could add mechanical vibration to a system).